# flutter local notification can't set notification for next day

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I use flutter local notification package in my project and when I try to set a notification in custom day it doesn't work .
for example : if I set notification for tomorrow at 3:15 it will range in the day I set the notification in not "in the next day" , Here is my code after adding custom time for notification to test this case

```
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      task.id!.toInt(),
      task.title,
      task.note,
      tz.TZDateTime(tz.local, now.year, now.month, now.day + 1, 15, 17),
      // _convertTime(hour, minutes, task),

      const NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'your channel id 3',
          'your channel name',
          channelDescription: 'your channel description',
          priority: Priority.max,
          importance: Importance.max,
          sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('notification_sound'),
        ),
        iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(sound: 'notification_sound.wav'),
      ),
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
      matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time,
      payload: "${task.title}|${task.note}|${task.date}|",
    );
  }
```

can you help me with a way to set the notification for a spacific day

Answer (score 1):

I found that this error happen because I set

```
matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time,
```

and that tell the app to run this every day so even if you set it for tomorrow it will also run today so I solved that by setting this to

```
matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.dateAndTime,
```